# How may I constrain the parameter types to use a comparator less than on the data?

Tags: c#

I need to sort the data that I use on the main function. How may I constrain the parameter types to use comparator less than to order the numbers?

These are the instructions I have for the code:

> In this assignment, you will implement a generic ordered SortedLinkedList class based upon the
>   generic LinkedList class of your design. The use of a framework or third-party packages is
>   prohibited. You can either utilize inheritance or composition in your implementation.
>   The class must support a single Add method that accepts a single generic parameter as shown in
>   the signature below. This parameter will be inserted into the list in its proper sequence
>   (dictionary order, case-insensitive).
>   public void Add(T element)
>
> There are four conditions that must be handled in your insert method:
>   1. The list is empty
>   2. The new element is smaller than the first element
>   3. The new element is larger than the last element
>   4. The new element is larger than the first element and smaller than the last element
>
> Demonstrate that your class is functional by creating an ordered list of integers, adding the test
>   data (given below), and iterating over the list to display the contents of the list (in node order).
>   Integer data: 7, 6, 10, 15, 4, 0, 10, -5, 3, 11, 6, 3, 0, 1, and 8

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Inheritance_SortedLinkedList_Generics
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SortedDoublyLinkedList<int> List = new SortedDoublyLinkedList<int>();

            List.Add(7);
            List.Add(6);
            List.Add(10);
            List.Add(15);
            List.Add(4);
            List.Add(0);
            List.Add(10);
            List.Add(-5);
            List.Add(3);
            List.Add(11);
            List.Add(6);
            List.Add(3);
            List.Add(0);
            List.Add(1);
            List.Add(8);

            List.Print();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

public class SortedDoublyLinkedList<T> : LinkedList<T> where T : struct
{
    public void Add(T element) 
    {   //if the list is empty
        if(head == null)
        {   //allocates memory for the first node 
            //head and tail point to the one and only node
            head = new Node<T>(element);
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {   //new node becomes new head of list
            var oldHead = head;

            //head now points to new node containing data
            head = new Node<T>(element);
            head.next = oldHead;

            oldHead.previous = head;
        }
    }
    //prints the elements of the list
    public void Print()
    {
        if (head != null)
        {
            head.Print();
        }  
    }

    //default constructor for creating the list
    public SortedDoublyLinkedList()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    public Node<T> head { get; set; }
    public Node<T> tail { get; set; }
}

public class Node<T>
{
    public T data { get; set; }
    public Node<T> next { get; set; }
    public Node<T> previous { get; set; }

    public Node(T i)
    {
        data = i;
        next = null;
        previous = null;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.Write("<-|" + data + "|->");

        if(next != null)
        {
            next.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used the **where T : struct** command, but I don't know if this will work. I understand that I cannot create a restriction for the T data type to be only integers.

Comment: No one here can answer this question properly. Only your teacher can provide clarification on the assignment, and in particular how they expect you to handle comparisons for the purpose of the assignment. You may be prohibited from using built-in interfaces, and instead be required to invent your own comparison mechanism (e.g. a delegate). You need to discuss this with your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

You want to constrain the type to implement [`IComparable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=netframework-4.8).

```
public class SortedDoublyLinkedList<T> : LinkedList<T> where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't constrain the type such that a specific operator (less than) is defined, unfortunately. Instead you have to implement a Comparer (see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1.system-collections-icomparer-compare?view=netframework-4.8)). After all, if you have a truly generic sorted list, the type could be anything, and therefore the meaning of 'less than' cannot be specified in a generic fashion. However, the matter is complicated by the fact that the assignment asks for "dictionary order, case insensitive", which can only possibly apply to strings, or objects that can be converted to strings. Therefore, you could perhaps call element.ToString().ToLower() and sort alphabetically, yet alphabetical sorts won't work for integers ("7" is > "10"). Really it seems to me the question is flawed and you should ask for clarification.